# How to improve the picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do a drawing of triangles built in square, alternately in and out, as shown in the figure,so that the points P, Q, R and S are collinear. 
[image]

However, I made an ugly design.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw(0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[fill=gray!40] (1.8,2.4)--(0,5)--(5,5)--(1.8,2.4);
\draw[fill=gray!40] (0,0)--(3.2,2.4)--(5,0)--(0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!40] (7.4,1.8)--(5,5)--(5,0)--(7.4,1.8);
\draw[fill=gray!40] (0,0)--(-2.4,3.2)--(0,5)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How to improve it?

Comment: Just move around the coordinates until they fit your requirements on beauty? If you want to put more effort in, make a nice triangle and use `\foreach` to put it into four places with proper rotation; Use the ìntersections` package… Maybe you can specify what exactly you want to improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.pic` key can be quite useful in such cases of repeated small shapes. It also accepts parameters as needed. The general syntax is like

```
\tikzset{
   pics/picname/.style={
       code={
            <pic commands>},
   }
}
```

but in most cases with less than two parameters, this shorter syntax suffices

```
\tikzset{    
    picname/.pic={ 
       <pic commands> },
}
```

Refer to the TikZ manual for more details.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  tr/.pic={
    \draw[pattern=dots] (0,0) -- (0,4cm) -- (30:2cm) -- cycle;
    \node at ($(0,0)!1.2!(30:2cm)$) {#1};
  }
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path pic[rotate=  0]  at (4,0) {tr=S};
\path pic[rotate= 90]  at (4,0) {tr=R};
\path pic[rotate=-90]  at (0,4) {tr=Q};
\path pic[rotate=180]  at (0,4) {tr=P};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]